# Get Notification data in laravel using ajax

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, laravel

I have a notification set in laravel and it worked fine, and when I click the notification I want to show a dynamic modal with the notification detail in it, but I couldn't figure how to get each data from the data column

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kTliV.png)

here is my code

### Javascript

````
    $('.detail-btn').click(function() {
        const id = $(this).attr('data-id');
        console.log(id)
        $.ajax({
            url: '/admin/notification/' + id,
            type: 'GET',
            data: {
                'id': id,
            },
            success: function(data) {
                console.log(data);
                $('#judul').html(data.id);
                $('#detail').html(data.data)
            }
        });
    });```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your "data" variable is a json array. Currently, you're outputting the whole array in your modal. So if you want to display a specific attribute from that array, you can simply change:

```
$('#detail').html(data.data)
```

to

```
$('#detail').html(data.data.name)
```

Or whichever other attribute you want to display in your modal.

Comment: this answer my question, one thing i need to mention is, i have to parseJson my array first, thanks